# Create Hibernate criterion to select on property of property

Tags: hibernate

I have two classes:

```
class A {
    private B b;
    /* ... */
}

class B {
    private String c;
    /* ... */
}
```

Can I create a Hibernate criteria to select all A where b.c = "foo" ?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252468/hibernate-criteria-and-multiple-join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
criteriaForA.createAlias("b", "b").add(Restrictions.eq("b.c", "valueForC");
```