# How to implement with hibernate criteria Object the select query with inner join

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I'm new with Hibernate and Criteria Query.
So I have implemented the query in HQL:

```
select A.mobilephone
    B.userNick
    C.creditCard
from mobile_table A
inner join user_table B
    on A.codmobile=B.codmobile
inner join Credit C 
    on A.mobileCredit= C.mobileCredit
```

How can I implement it with Hibernate Criteria Object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your example is just a native SQL , not the HQL . Anyway , you can use the following methods from the [Criteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html) API to construct the desired Criteria object :

- Use the [setProjection(Projection projection)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#setProjection%28org.hibernate.criterion.Projection%29) to define the select clause
- Use the [createCriteria(String associationPath,String alias)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#createCriteria%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to define the inner join

For example , if the SQL is :

```
select
    TableA.columnA ,TableB.columnB ,TableC.columnC
from TableA 
inner join TableB on TableA.tableB_id=TableB.id
inner join TableC on TableA.tableC_id=TableC.id
where TableA.columnAA="AAA"
and TableB.columnBB="BBB"
and TableC.columnCC="CCC"
```

Then the Criteria object will be:

```
List<Object[]>resultList= (List<Object[]>)session.createCriteria(TableA.class, "aliasOfTableA") 
                .add(Restrictions.eq("aliasOfTableA.columnAA", "AAA"))  
                .createCriteria("aliasOfTableA.tableBId" , "aliasOfTableB")
                .add(Restrictions.eq("aliasOfTableB.columnBB", "BBB"))
                .createCriteria("aliasOfTableA.tableCId" , "aliasOfTableC")
                .add(Restrictions.eq("aliasOfTableC.columnCC", "CCC"))
                .setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
                        .add( Projections.property("aliasOfTableA.columnA") )
                        .add( Projections.property("aliasOfTableB.columnB"))
                        .add( Projections.property("aliasOfTableC.columnC") )
                ).list();

for (Object[] obj : resultList) {
        System.out.println(obj[0]); //print the value from TableA.columnA
        System.out.println(obj[1]); //print the value from TableB.columnB
        System.out.println(obj[2]); //print the value from TableC.columnC
}
```

Please note that all parameters in the `Criteria` use the property name and class name in the mapped Java entities.

Comment: than you Very much....I think your suggestion are very so close to what i would to obtain...So only need to try the solution.
I have  a question:
if i would insert a restriction i have to put it in projections??
tanx for all

Comment: Good solution but, Sorry, I have an Stupid DOubt: in the code above maybe do you intend do write
.createCriteria("aliasOfTableA.tableBId" , "aliasOfTableB"), and aliasofTableA (refers at the line above?)
instead of .createCriteria("AliasOfTableA.tableBId" , "aliasOfTableB")

Comment: Yes , you are right . Typed wrong before , i  just corrected it

Comment: Just a bit confused here, how does 'aliasOfTableB' denotes TableB here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that's HQL? Looks like native SQL to me.

In order to use Criteria your entities need to be mapped and associated with each other (since Criteria only allows navigating association paths). I think you could get more help if you give some details about your mappings.

Comment: Yes it is in native SQL, because i prefer to write it on thi way. So the association mappings i think is not interesting, but how i can translate a sql native wrote above in Hibernate Criteria, because I need to understand how i can do it.
Have you an idea?
Looking inside java-stack i have found the link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252468/hibernate-criteria-and-multiple-join

but i don't understand some parts of it...
Who could help me??

Comment: Hibernate Criteria **requires** mapping your tables to persistent classes and defining associations.