# Hibernate check equal of two unrelated column

Tags: hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have sample entity as following

```
class Book{
  int id
  String name
  int sid
}

class Author {
   int id
   String name
   List<Book> books
   int mid
}
```

Its not good design, I know that just trying to explain a scenario.

Now my questions is, Is there any way I can check equal of two unrelated column

e.g

```
session.createCriteria(Author.class, "author")
       .createAlias("books", "book")
       .add(Restrictions.eq("author.mid","book.sid")
       .list()
```

Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the recommended way but `Restriction.sqlRestriction` worked for me to get the desired output

```
session.createCriteria(Author.class, "author")
       .createAlias("books", "book")
       .add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("author.mid","book.sid")
       .list()
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion Criteria API doesn't support join unrelated entities. Try to use HQL as follows instead of Criteria API.

```
session.createQuery("from Book as book INNER JOIN Author as author WHERE book.sid = author.mid").list();
```

Comment: you do not have `on` part for join. this query wont work. update your answer

Answer (score 1):

I think do not require **Restrictions.eq("author.mid","book.sid")**. I hope this helps you.

Normal Sql Statement:

```
SELECT A.*, B.* FROM Author A, Books b WHERE A.ID=B.id ;
```

Criteria join:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Author.class);
    criteria.setFetchMode("books", FetchMode.JOIN)
    List list = criteria.list();
```

if you have further restrictions then you have to add restrictions

```
 .add(Restrictions.eq("id", 2));
```

[Example Criteria](http://learningviacode.blogspot.com/2013/02/criteria-and-inner-joins.html)

[Subquery-Criteria](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tip-subquery-criteriaquery/)

[Similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164727/how-to-implement-with-hibernate-criteria-object-the-select-query-with-inner-join)

Comment: I do need it. I am giving just a sample here. in actual query mid=sid is required

Comment: if requries ,we can also the condition .add(Restrictions.eq("author.mid","book.sid")

Comment: Then your ex should work : session.createCriteria(Author.class, "author") .createAlias("books", "book") .add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("author.mid","book.sid") .list()