# Hibernate Criteria Join with 3 Tables

Tags: hibernate, join, criteria

I am looking for a hibernate criteria to get following:

Dokument.class
is mapped to Role
roleId

Role.class
has a ContactPerson
contactId

Contact.class
FirstName
LastName

I want to search for First or LastName on the Contact class and retrieve a list of Dokuments connected.

I have tried something like this:

```
session.createCriteria(Dokument.class)
.setFetchMode("role",FetchMode.JOIN)
.setFetchMode("contact",FetchMode.JOIN)
.add(Restrictions.eq("LastName","Test")).list();
```

I get an error could not resolve property "LastName" for class "Dokument"

Can someone explain why the join searches on Dokument and not on all joined tables?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

The fetch mode only says that the association must be fetched. If you want to add restrictions on an associated entity, you must create an alias, or a subcriteria. I generally prefer using aliases, but YMMV:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Dokument.class, "dokument");
c.createAlias("dokument.role", "role"); // inner join by default
c.createAlias("role.contact", "contact");
c.add(Restrictions.eq("contact.lastName", "Test"));
return c.list();
```

This is of course well explained in the [Hibernate reference manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations), and the [javadoc for Criteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html) even has examples.  Read the documentation: it has plenty of useful information.

Comment: JB thanks so much. Yeah I have read the specs, but for a Hibernate newbee it is quite hard to wrap one's head around all the Hibernate lingo. Again THANKS IT WORKS :-)

Comment: btw what is an association, just some reference?

Comment: An association is when an entity is linked to another entity with a OneToOne, OneToMany, ManyToOne or ManyToMany... association.

Comment: @JBNizet I would argue that the reference manual does not explain well.  Unless you're better than me at relating cats and kittens to business objects.

Comment: After 10 years of using Hibernate, I finally found this, which helped me forward. Thanks :)