# I want to get the row count of 2 different values from the database.How i write the hibernate criteria query for that?

Tags: hibernate

I want to get the row count of 2 different values from the database.How i write the hibernate criteria query for that?
For example, in my table contain a field named 'status' and its values are 0 and 1.How could i get how many 0 and how many 1 are in my table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do

```
select count(status) from table group by status
```

Hibernate Criteria

```
List result = session.createCriteria(Table.class)       
                    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                            .add(Projections.groupProperty("status"))
                            .add(Projections.count("status"))           
                    ).list();
```

Comment: I have another doubt ..How to integrate two criteria queries of different tables into one?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726396/hibernate-criteria-join-with-3-tables