# Using hibernate criteria in one to many mapping (Search header table with line table column as one of search criteria)

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria, hibernate-onetomany

I have two classes InvoiceHeader and InvoiceLine with a one to many (One InvoiceHeader maps to multiple InvoiceLine) mapping between them.

```
class InvoiceHeader
{
   private int id;
   private String title;
   private Set <InvoiceLine> invoiceLines; 
}

class InvoiceLine
{
    private int id;
    private int itemId;
    private int itemName;  
    private InvoiceHeader invoiceHeader;      
}
```

Now i want to search InvoiceHeaders based on InvoiceHeader.title and InvoiceLine.itemId. Is there a way i can use hibernate Criteria to search it. Bascially while using hibernate criteria , i'm unsure about how to put InvoiceLine.itemId in criteria of InvoiceHeader. If this is not possible using criteria then please suggest me some other approach.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at the answer given here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8726763/87832

This pretty much explains it. Take a look at the Hibernate documentation to see other use cases: [Hibernate Criteria Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations)