# How to add fields for joins in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am new to hibernate and will require your assistance.

My goal is to define hibernate classes and eventually run the following SQL query

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT *  FROM {quiz_question_instances} WHERE quiz =5 ) AS mqqi
LEFT JOIN {question_usages} mqu ON mqu.id =139
LEFT JOIN {question_attempts} mqea ON mqea.questionusageid = mqu.id
AND mqea.questionid = mqqi.question
```

I do not know how to do Joins in hibernate. Should I create entity classes for all the tables mentioned in this query?

Also, I am using spring to display this data to a webpage. I have a dao layer defined too.  How do i write this query in my dao layer?

Thanks for all the help!

EDIT:-

Attached the columns of the database tables.

**Question Attempts**

[image]

**Question Usages**

[image]

**Quiz Question Instances**

[image]

Comment: In hibernate you dont work with tables but you work with objects..It would be of use to us if you give your object structure and how you mapped it

Comment: I create a class for each table. I map every column to a variable and use the @Column annotation. I do not know how to declare the columns which come from the join as a variable. That is where I am seeking help :)

Comment: Hibernet handles joins itself, u have to only create its **hbm** or declared **annotation**

Comment: Hi Ashish, can you let me know any tutorial that i can follow for this?

Comment: As said above here, hibernate automaticly maps joincolumns..You have to use the ManyToOne / ManyToMany (jointable) annotations for this..In combination with JoinColumn

Answer (score 0):

You can help in the interfaz Criteria (org.hibernate.Criteria), HQL,...

Here there is a solution for joins:

> [Hibernate Criteria Join with 3 Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726396/hibernate-criteria-join-with-3-tables)

You also have an explication:

> http://kruders.com/hibernate/hibernate-criteria-on-multiple-tables/

I hope help you.