# How to have criteria from multiple entities Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have entities like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "titul")
public class Titul {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "titul") 
  private Set<Autorstvo> autorstvo;

  @Column (name = "nazov")
  private String nazov;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "autorstvo")
public class Autorstvo {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_autor") 
    private Autor autor;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "autor")
public class Autor {
    @Column (name = "meno")
    private String meno;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "autor")
    private Set<Autorstvo> autorstvo;
}
```

And i want to have SELECT by criteria Titul.nazov and Autor.meno

So far i did this in Hibernate:

```
Criteria critT = session.createCriteria(Titul.class);

critT.add(Restrictions.like("nazov", titul));
critT.createAlias("titul.autorstvo", "autorstvo");
critT.createAlias("autorstvo.autor", "autor");
critT.add(Restrictions.ilike("autor.meno", autor));
    critT.list();
```

But It always ends when trying to execut critT.list()

What am I doing wrong? How can i add JOINed criterias to criteria in Hibernate?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8726763/2231632 - possible duplicate

Comment: This solved my problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726396/hibernate-criteria-join-with-3-tables/8726763#8726763

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem:

[Hibernate Criteria Join with 3 Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726396/hibernate-criteria-join-with-3-tables/8726763#8726763)

Forgot to add alias to criteria creation also

> The fetch mode only says that the association must be fetched. If you
>   want to add restrictions on an associated entity, you must create an
>   alias, or a subcriteria. I generally prefer using aliases, but YMMV:
>
> ```
> Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Dokument.class, "dokument");
> c.createAlias("dokument.role", "role"); // inner join by default
> c.createAlias("role.contact", "contact");
> c.add(Restrictions.eq("contact.lastName", "Test"));
> return c.list();
> ```
>
> This is of course well explain in the Hibernate reference manual, and
>   the javadoc for Criteria even has examples. Read the documentation: it
>   has plenty of useful information.