# Hibernate - Adding properties of another class in Criteria Restrictions

Tags: java, database, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a table Loan application whose pojo is

```
class LoanApplication{
int id;
int loanNo;
...
}
```

I have another pojo

```
class LoanFlow{
int id;
int loanId;
date reviewDate;
...
}
```

Here loanId of loanFlow is the foreign key mapped to the id of LoanApplication.

I have to fetch all the loan applications with the reviewDate.

I am trying to write a criteria like:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(LoanApplication.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", someId));
```

How can I fetch the reviewDate also from LoanFlow with this criteria.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have criteria from multiple entities Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23395216/how-to-have-criteria-from-multiple-entities-hibernate)

Comment: Is there ManyToOne or OneToMany annotations to the relationship between entities?

Comment: @adyjr No there is no such mapping

Answer (score 1):

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(LoanApplication.class, "loApp");
criteria.createAlias("loApp.loanFlow", "flow");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("flow.id", 1));
```

> You can directlly use HQL also.
>   using createQuery()

Comment: loanFlow is a separate class, it is not inside loanApplication.

Comment: But LoanApplication maped with LoanFlow

Comment: you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164727/how-to-implement-with-hibernate-criteria-object-the-select-query-with-inner-join

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with subqueries, if there isn't ManyToOne or OneToMany annotations to the relationship between entities:

```
DetachedCriteria subQuery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(LoanFlow.class, "loanFlow");

/*Here there is a between, but you can change it to your necessity*/
subQuery.add(Restrictions.between("loanFlow.reviewDate", dateBegin, dateEnd));
subQuery.setProjection(Projections.property("loanFlow.loanId"));

Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(LoanApplication.class, "loanApplication");        
Subqueries.propertyIn("loanApplication.id", subQuery);

List<LoanApplication> list = criteria.list();
```