# Convert SQL to Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I'm a newbie with Hibernate so I have difficulties to convert my SQL requests.
I have the following SQL request :

```
SELECT product_name, sum(quantity)
FROM final_product
JOIN customer_order_entry ON final_product.final_product_id = customer_order_entry.final_product_id
JOIN customer_order ON customer_order_entry.customer_order_id = customer_order.customer_order_id
JOIN customer ON customer_order.customer_id = customer.customer_id
JOIN salesman ON customer.salesman_id = salesman.salesman_id
WHERE salesman.salesman_id = '1'
GROUP BY final_product.final_product_id 
LIMIT 3;
```

I want to have the same result with hibernate criteria.
But I don't know how to specify that I only want two rows as result. 
Plus, I can't figure out how should I recover the result (due to my "join", the result doesn't belong to only one class so I can't put my result in `List<Classname>` as I used to do).

For this moment, I coded this :

```
session.createCriteria(FinalProduct.class)
        .add(Projections.sum("quantity"))
            .setFetchMode("CustomerOrderEntry", FetchMode.JOIN)
        .setFetchMode("CustomerOrder", FetchMode.JOIN)
        .setFetchMode("Customer", FetchMode.JOIN)
        .setFetchMode("Salesman", FetchMode.JOIN)
        .add(Restrictions.eq("Salesman.salesmanId", new Integer(1))
        .add(Projections.groupProperty("FinalProduct.finalProductId"))
        c.setMaxResults(3);
```

Please, could you give me any clue ?

Comment: by using HQL you can achive same result so try HQL

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate Criteria Join with 3 Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726396/hibernate-criteria-join-with-3-tables)