# Hibernate criteria query a class with property（ a Set） of the class and property（a Set） of this property?

Tags: hibernate, criteria

```
class Article{
        private Long articleId;
        private Set<Tag> tags;
    }

class Tag{

    private Set<Article> articles;

   private Set<TagLocale> tagLocales; 
}

class TagLocale{
    private Tag tag;
    private String name;
}
```

when i using criteria query article by articleId，the same time ,hierarchical queries tags  and tagLocales，How can i do using criteria ?

Comment: will [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726396/hibernate-criteria-join-with-3-tables) help you.

Comment: does it solve your purpose

Comment: ok i will post the answer for your acceptance then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to joining 3 tables.

More or less the same have been answered here.

[hibernate-criteria-join-with-3-tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726396/hibernate-criteria-join-with-3-tables)