# How to set a criteria with child table

Tags: oracle, hibernate, criteria

I need to have query like this:

```
select * from TABLE where Source_KEY in (1,2);
```

My Hibernate class is like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE", schema = "SCH")
public class Table {
    private Long key;
    private Long id;
    private Source src;
}

Source is another entity class,
@Entity
@Table(name = "SOURCE", schema = "SCH")
public class Source{
private Long Source_KEY;
}
```

Now i have written a criteria but it seems to have an issue.
Please can anyone advice on this.

```
private static final List<String> STAY_SOURCE_KEY = asList(1,2);

criteria.add(Restrictions.in("Source_KEY", STAY_SOURCE_KEY));
```

This should be a list of Source class but how to to that in criteria. It has 
to form query like

```
select * from TABLE where Source_KEY in (1,2);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate Criteria Join with 3 Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726396/hibernate-criteria-join-with-3-tables)

Answer (score 1):

You need to join table. Use

```
criteria.createAlias("src","s");
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("s.Source_KEY", STAY_SOURCE_KEY));
```