# How do I join two different classes than the class on which criteria is created?

Tags: hibernate, left-join, hibernate-criteria

I have Class A on which on which criteria is created. Class B is mapped in class A. But I want to join class C with class B using criteria.

Class B and C are directly related.

I want the query something like:

```
select * from A
left outer join B on B.id = A.id
left outer join C on B.id = C.id
```

and

```
Criteria criteria = factory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(A.class, "A");
```

Comment: You should show the relevant parts of your A, B and C classes. Specifically how they relate to eachother. Also, your question is generally incomplete, you should explain an expected output based on an example input, and preferably what you have tried to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Answer is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726396/hibernate-criteria-join-with-3-tables