# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The multi-part identifier "s.message" could not be bound

Tags: java, hibernate

I tried create `sqlRestriction` in hibernate criteria but I have an error;
It is my query:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(PollEvent.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("type", 0));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("sendDate", fromDate));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.lt("sendDate", toDate));
        criteria.createAlias("call", "c");
        criteria.createAlias("c.operators", "o");
        criteria.createAlias("sms", "s");
        criteria.createAlias("pollEvent", "pp");

        if (!subscriberMSISDN.isEmpty()) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("c.callingnum", subscriberMSISDN));
        }
        if (!operatorNickname.isEmpty()) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("o.nickname", operatorNickname));
        }
        if (!operatorID.isEmpty()) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("o.operator_avaya_id", operatorID));
        }
        if (msg1 != null) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("LEN(s.message) - LEN(REPLACE(s.message,"+msg1+",'')) = 1 AND PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',REPLACE(s.message,"+msg1+",'')) = 0"));
        }
```

It is WHERE in my query:

...

```
where
        this_.TYPE=? 
        and this_.SEND_DATE>=? 
        and this_.SEND_DATE<? 
        and LEN(s.message) - LEN(REPLACE(s.message,0,'')) = 1 
        AND PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',REPLACE(s.message,0,'')) = 0]]
```

And it is error:

```
[2015-12-29T12:04:39.997+0600] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] [tid: _ThreadID=36 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(5)] [timeMillis: 1451369079997] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Error Rendering View[/reports/qcforcc_report.xhtml]
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2036)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1836)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1815)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2522)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2508)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2338)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2333)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1662)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:374)
    at kg.nurtelecom.qcforcc.dao.pools.jpa.PollEventJpaDao.getReport(PollEventJpaDao.java:137)
    at kg.nurtelecom.qcforcc.services.poll.PollEventService.getReport(PollEventService.java:90)
    at kg.nurtelecom.qcforcc.view.reports.QCforCCLazyDataModel.getReportDESC(QCforCCLazyDataModel.java:70)
    at kg.nurtelecom.qcforcc.view.reports.QCforCCLazyDataModel.load(QCforCCLazyDataModel.java:53)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.loadLazyData(DataTable.java:976)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.preRender(DataTableRenderer.java:95)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:83)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The multi-part identifier "s.message" could not be bound.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1635)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:426)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:372)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:6276)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1793)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:184)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:159)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:284)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:56)
    ... 80 more
]]
```

Error in this line `Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The multi-part identifier "s.message" could not be bound.`

I tried alias and not alias. I don't understend how write curectly.

**EDIT** in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082364/java-hibernate-criteria-select-subclass) like me and worck but my code not work

Comment: What about {s}.message?

Comment: @StanislavL Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '}'

Comment: Is the alias correctly created criteria.createAlias("sms", "s");?

Comment: Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(PollEvent.class, "PollEvent");
criteria.createAlias("PollEvent.sms", "s");

Comment: Check also this http://ch-express.blogspot.com.by/2008/06/hibernate-criteria-sqlrestriction-alias.html to define alias correctly

Comment: another aliases in this class works normaly

Comment: @ StanislavL nothing helped