# Can Hibernate Criteria query for subclasses using Restrictions.in?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a number of classes mapped as an inheritance hierarchy into a single table.

I would like to use the following `Criteria` query but this results in a `ClassCastException` since `Class` cannot be cast to `String`.

```
Set<Class> childClasses = new HashSet<>();
childClasses.add(Child1.class);
childClasses.add(Child2.class);

session.createCriteria(Parent.class)
       .add(Restrictions.in("class", childClasses)
       .list();
```

I note that Hibernate does support specifying a single class using `Restrictions.eq("class", childClass)` so I can workaround by using a `Disjunction`'. I also know that this would work if my resriction was based on the discriminator strings for each subclass but I would prefer not to use these.

It is possible to use `Criteria` in this manner? The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082364/java-hibernate-criteria-select-subclass) suggests that it works when the class is a property of the class you are basing your `Criteria` on but it doesn't seem to work in the case I've shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code, I would say that this is a Hibernate bug.

For example, [`SimpleExpression`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/4.3/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/criterion/SimpleExpression.java#L116) (returned by `Restrictions.eq`) calls [`criteriaQuery.getTypedValue`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/4.3/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/loader/criteria/CriteriaQueryTranslator.java#L593) which handles conversion of `Class` value to the corresponding discriminator value.

[`InExpression`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/4.3/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/criterion/InExpression.java#L103) (returned by `Restrictions.in`) adds values as they are, without conversion. That's why you get `ClassCastException`, because later an attempt to cast `Class` to `String` is made (obviously the type of your discriminator value is `String`).

You could avoid using this form until it's fixed (you already suggested the proper workarounds), or, if you would really like to stick to using `Class` objects directly, then you could implement custom `InExpression` in your project. For example, something like:

```
public class ClassInExpression extends InExpression {
    private static final String CLASS = "class";
    private final Collection<Class> values;

    public ClassInExpression(Collection<Class> values) {
        super(CLASS, values.toArray(new Object[values.size()]));
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public TypedValue[] getTypedValues(Criteria criteria, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery) {
        if (criteriaQuery.getTypeUsingProjection(criteria, CLASS).isComponentType()) {
            return super.getTypedValues(criteria, criteriaQuery);
        }
        return convertToDiscriminatorValues(criteria, criteriaQuery);
    }

    private TypedValue[] convertToDiscriminatorValues(Criteria criteria, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery) {
        List<TypedValue> resultList = new ArrayList<TypedValue>();
        for (Object value : values) {
            resultList.add(criteriaQuery.getTypedValue(criteria, CLASS, value));
        }
        return resultList.toArray(new TypedValue[resultList.size()]);
    }
}
```

Then you would use it instead of `Restrictions.in`:

```
session.createCriteria(Parent.class)
    .add(new ClassInExpression(childClasses))
    .list()
```

Comment: And the defect was rejected since Criteria is deprecated in Hibernate 5.

Comment: @Mark I submitted the [pull request](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/1277), it has been accepted. The fix will be available on both 5.1 and 5.0.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm using 4.3 for now with the code above but good to know it will work out of the box if/when we move to 5.x