# hibernate criteria API with multiple left inner joins

Tags: hibernate, inner-join, criteria-api

The table relationships is as follows:

- A users table with columns identity, username, age
- An addresses table with columns identity, type, street
- A user_address_associations table with columns identity, userid and addressid. userid has foreign key relationship to users.identity and addressid has foreign key relationsip to addresses.identity.

I will like to select all users older than 18 years with address type set to 1.  Hibernate mappings for User and Address entities exist but there is no associations defined within the mapping from User to Address. The only link between a User and Address is specified via the user_address_associations table.  Also, the User class does not defined an Addresses property.

The raw SQL will be:

```
select * from users 
inner join user_address_associations   
on user_address_associations.userid=users.identity
inner join addresses 
on user_address_associations.addressid=addresses.identity and addresses.type=1
where db.users.age >= 18
```

Using the Hibernate 3.6.5 Criteria API, I started with this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);

// how to do the join to addresses table through user_address_associations table?

// where clause
criteria.add(Restrictions.gt("Age", 1176));
```

Question is, how do I formuate the joins?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate Criteria and multiple join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252468/hibernate-criteria-and-multiple-join)

Comment: @mindas, thanks for the response.  I just read through the answer you posted in referenced link but still need some clarity with   .createCriteria("b", "join_between_a_b") and how this translates to the join between class A and B.  Still also trying to understand the API docs.

Comment: "how this translates to the join between class A and B" -- if you want to see the actual generated SQL, enable trace logging for org.hibernate.SQL. If you want to understand how Hibernate does it internally, you need to study Hibernate's source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible. Hibernate queries, (HQL or Criteria) only use entities, their persistent fields and their associations. If the join table is not mapped and is not used to define an association between ther User and Address entities, you won't be able to define queries using this table with Hibernate, except SQL queries of course.

Comment: Thank you.  Will look into modifying entities to define relationships.