# Joining 3 tables with hIbernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Is there a way to write the following sql using hibernate criteria?

```
select A.columnA1, B.columnB1, C.columnC1 
from A inner join B on A.fk_id = B.id 
inner join C on C.fk_id = B.id
```

This question is slightly different from [Hibernate Criteria and multiple join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252468/hibernate-criteria-and-multiple-join)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate Criteria Join with 3 Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726396/hibernate-criteria-join-with-3-tables)

Comment: No, they are not the same.

Comment: What is the difference to your problem?

Comment: [Hibernate Criteria Join with 3 Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726396/hibernate-criteria-join-with-3-tables) and [Hibernate Criteria and multiple join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252468/hibernate-criteria-and-multiple-join) are similar. The answer that you provided solves the following SQL: select A.columnA1, B.columnB1, C.columnC1 
from A inner join B on **A.fk_id = B.id** inner join C on **B.fk_id = C.id**